# How can I validate a culture code with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I really don't understand regex and I also can't find any regex rule to validate culture codes as: en-GB, en-UK, az-AZ-Cyrl, others.

How can I validate these codes with a regular expression?

Comment: That link should be removed as it leads to a hijacked site.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can validate with this :

```
/^[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[A-Z]{2,3}(?:-[a-zA-Z]{4})?)?$/
```

Here is how it works

```
^       <- Starts with
[a-z]   <- From a to z (lower-case)
{2,3}   <- Repeated at least 2 times, at most 3
(?:     <- Non capturing group
   -        <- The "-" character
   [A-Z]     <- From a to z (upper-case)
   {2,3}     <- Repeated at least 2 times, at most 3
   (?:       <- Non capturing group
       -         <- The "-" character
       [a-zA-Z]  <- from a to Z (case insensitive)
       {4}      <- Repeated 4 times
   )         <- End of the group
   ?         <- Facultative
 )       <- End of the group
 ?       <- Facultative
 $       <- Ends here
```

You can also replace the last non capturing group by `(?:-(?:Cyrl|Latn))?` if the only options are Cyrl and Latn

Comment: Thank you Colin Hebert and Eumiro as well :)

Comment: Why is that regex prefered over the one defined by the specs?

Comment: @Stephane I didn't know there was a regular expression in the specs. Where did you find it?

Comment: hehe, it's the answer just below, and it is documented here : http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#language.
Although this RFC is obsolete, the pattern will still match the newer version of the RFC(4646 and 4647) which are stricter.

Comment: @Stephane, w3.org isn't really the spec here (not the one for Tags for identifying languages anyway) and actually the provided regex doesn't strictly respect the RFC. It would require something slightly more complicated to actually follow rfc4646 2.1. The advantage "which isn't really one" of my solution is that it respects the list provided by the OP and would give less false positives. The problem would be that it doesn't respect the RFC and one language/variant/region not in the list could be not valid.

Comment: This regex will not match RFC1766-compliant locale identifiers, as it doesn't specially treat `i-` or `x-` prefixed locales, e.g. both `i-sami-no` and `x-klingon` will not be matched by this. The answer below is more accurate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3962783/83444

Comment: This will not match `zh-Hant-HK`, a valid culture code under RFC 3066

Comment: Not even worth it.  It will either match some resource's culture or it won't.  The only kind of fallback that makes sense is from some specific set of subtags to a basic langauge tag, unless you're going to create really complex fallback rules, so the only thing you really need to parse is the first subtag (the language).  Even after following the spec, someone will say "but that won't match Klingon!".  Just ensure it's a case-insensitive alpha-numeric string with components separated by dashes.  That's my opinion.

Comment: Counterexample: `x-klingon`.

Answer (score 9):

This is what I found in the Dublin Core / W3C xsd's : http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

```
  <xs:simpleType name="language" id="language"> 
    <xs:annotation> 
      <xs:documentation 
        source="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#language"/> 
    </xs:annotation> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token"> 
      <xs:pattern 
        value="[a-zA-Z]{1,8}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8})*"
                id="language.pattern"> 
        <xs:annotation> 
          <xs:documentation 
                source="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt"> 
            pattern specifies the content of section 2.12 of XML 1.0e2
            and RFC 3066 (Revised version of RFC 1766).
          </xs:documentation> 
        </xs:annotation> 
      </xs:pattern> 
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Then the pattern is :

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,8}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8})*
```

Comment: If you add line anchors and a non-capturing group, it becomes `^[a-zA-Z]{1,8}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8})*$`

Answer (score 3):

According https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag the regexp can be:

```
/^[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[a-zA-Z]{4})?(?:-[A-Z]{2,3})?$/
```

From wiki:

> a single primary language subtag based on a two-letter language code from ISO 639-1 (2002) or a three-letter code from ISO 639-2 (1998), ISO 639-3 (2007) or ISO 639-5 (2008), or registered through the BCP 47 process and composed of five to eight letters;
>
> an optional script subtag, based on a four-letter script code from ISO 15924 (usually written in title case);
>
> an optional region subtag based on a two-letter country code from ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 (usually written in upper case), or a three-digit code from UN M.49 for geographical regions;

Comment: "a three-digit code" I don't see any digit-matching characters in that regex.

Comment: Counterexample: `x-klingon`.

Answer (score 1):

According to

> ## [RFC 3066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3066)
>
> ### 2. The Language tag
>
> #### 2.1 Language tag syntax
>
> The language tag is composed of one or more parts: A primary language subtag and a (possibly empty) series of subsequent subtags.
>
> The syntax of this tag in ABNF [RFC 2234] is:
>
> ```
> Language-Tag = Primary-subtag *( "-" Subtag )
>
> Primary-subtag = 1*8ALPHA
>
> Subtag = 1*8(ALPHA / DIGIT)
> ```
>
> The productions ALPHA and DIGIT are imported from RFC 2234; they denote respectively the characters `A` to `Z` in upper or lower case and the digits from `0` to `9`.  The character "`-`" is HYPHEN-MINUS (ABNF: `%x2D`).

the `Language-Tag` is

```
/^[a-z]{1,8}(?:\-[a-z0-9]{1,8})*$/i
(A Javascript regular expression. The “i” denotes case-insensitiveness.)
```

Answer (score -5):

^(?i:AF|AX|AL|DZ|AS|AD|AO|AI|AQ|AG|AR|AM|AW|AU|AT|AZ|BS|BH|BD|BB|BY|BE|BZ|BJ|BM|BT|BO|BQ|BA|BW|BV|BR|IO|BN|BG|BF|BI|KH|CM|CA|CV|KY|CF|TD|CL|CN|CX|CC|CO|KM|CG|CD|CK|CR|CI|HR|CU|CW|CY|CZ|DK|DJ|DM|DO|EC|EG|SV|GQ|ER|EE|ET|FK|FO|FJ|FI|FR|GF|PF|TF|GA|GM|GE|DE|GH|GI|GR|GL|GD|GP|GU|GT|GG|GN|GW|GY|HT|HM|VA|HN|HK|HU|IS|IN|ID|IR|IQ|IE|IM|IL|IT|JM|JP|JE|JO|KZ|KE|KI|KP|KR|KW|KG|LA|LV|LB|LS|LR|LY|LI|LT|LU|MO|MK|MG|MW|MY|MV|ML|MT|MH|MQ|MR|MU|YT|MX|FM|MD|MC|MN|ME|MS|MA|MZ|MM|NA|NR|NP|NL|NC|NZ|NI|NE|NG|NU|NF|MP|NO|OM|PK|PW|PS|PA|PG|PY|PE|PH|PN|PL|PT|PR|QA|RE|RO|RU|RW|BL|SH|KN|LC|MF|PM|VC|WS|SM|ST|SA|SN|RS|SC|SL|SG|SX|SK|SI|SB|SO|ZA|GS|SS|ES|LK|SD|SR|SJ|SZ|SE|CH|SY|TW|TJ|TZ|TH|TL|TG|TK|TO|TT|TN|TR|TM|TC|TV|UG|UA|AE|GB|US|UM|UY|UZ|VU|VE|VN|VG|VI|WF|EH|YE|ZM|ZW)$

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Also, it's not properly formatted, and last but not least this does not answer the question, as the culture code format described in the question is more like `[a-z]{2,2}-[A-Z]{2,4}`