# PHP preg_match , check if language is defined in url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to test for a language match in a url.

Url will be like : `http://www.domainname.com/en/#m=4&guid=%some_param%`

I want to check if there is an existing language code within the url.  I was thinking something between these lines :

`^(.*:)\/\/([a-z\-.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)$`

or

`^(http|https:)\/\/([a-z\-.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)$`

I'm not that sharp with regex. can anyone help or point me towards the right direction ?

Comment: What are existing language codes?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it would be a long list, some of them would be fi,sv,no,it etc..

Comment: There are several regxp out in the wild to test for valid language tags; e.g. http://schneegans.de/lv/ or the possible duplicate SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962543/how-can-i-validate-a-culture-code-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: @feeela, this does not match my requirements though

Answer (score 1):

[https]+://[a-z-]+.([a-z])+/
try this,
http://www.regexr.com/ this is a easy site for creating regex

Answer (score 1):

If you know the data you are testing is a url then I would not bother adding all of the url parts to the regex.  Keep it simple like: `/\/[a-z]{2}\//`  That looks for a two letter combination between two forward slashes.  If you need to capture the language code then wrap it in parentheses: `/\/([a-z]{2})\//`

Comment: thanks this is by far the simplest solution.. Would I be able to use preg_match_filter on this pattern to replace the language ?

Comment: If you want to replace it, use preg_replace like this: `$result = preg_replace('/\/[a-z]{2}\//', '/en/', $url)`  That would replace the language code with 'en'.

Comment: thanks that's awesome.. no need for string functions